# How to set value in dynamically added rows form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form in php with dynamically added rows (after clicking button the row is added). I want to fill the field with value "xx" and i want to do it in jquery.

This loop  create the dynamically added rows in jquery. I want to fill added fields with value "xx":

```
while($personsArrayLength>2){
        echo '
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var i = 2;
                var rowTemplate2 = jQuery.format($("#template2").html());

                rowTemplate2.value = "xx";
                addRow2();

                function addRow2(){
                    var ii = i++;
                    $("#app_here2").append(rowTemplate2(ii));
                    $("#delete_" + ii).click(function(){
                        $("#row_" + ii).remove();
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    ';
```

Here is html for that:

```
function addRows2(){

    global $personsError_css;
    $personsArray = $_POST['persons'];
    JB_var_dump($_POST['whichRow']);
        $html = '<table id="template2" align="right" style="display:none; ">
            <tr id="row_{0}">
                <td><input type="text" size="52" id="persons" name="persons[]" maxlength="100"></td>
                <td><img src="/../_img/row_del.png" id="delete_{0}" alt="usun"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="list2" style="margin-left:200px;">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" size="52" name="persons[]" maxlength="100" style="'.$personsError_css.';" value="'.$personsArray[1].'"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="app_here2"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
        return $html;
}
```

This is properly filled form
    [image]

In this epty fields I want to add values "xx"
[image]

Sorry for my english.

How can i set values in added rows? What i should change in my code?
Thanks for help.

Comment: do you want to set a placeholder? until the person types in something the placeholder will fill the textbox else.. `rowTemplate2.find('input:empty').val('xx')`

Answer (score 1):

Change your 'addRow2' to this:

```
function addRow2(){
    var ii = i++;
    $("#app_here2").append(rowTemplate2(ii));
    //UPDATE: var rowTemplate2 is not a jQuery Object, as i thought
    $("#template2").find("input:empty").val("xx");; // added this row
    $("#delete_" + ii).click(function(){
        $("#row_" + ii).remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunettly. The script is stopped in moment:
'rowTemplate2.find('input:empty').val('xx')' and doesn't continued.

Comment: add ';' .. so copy my solution again, because i missed a semicolon.. but i dont think, that this will cause the problem... may you press F12 and say me, what you see?

Comment: Found my error. var rowTemplate2 is not a jQuery Object, as i thought

Comment: It's not semicolon. Here is link after my F12 clicking:
[link](http://codepaste.net/314b3n)

Comment: ok... i expected the console :D .. do you know about developer tools? which browser ure using? is your code in your post working? i dont know `jQuery.format()`

Comment: Your questions is very hard for me because i work not on my own code. I know php , not jquery and i try to learn it :D I use firebug in mozilla.
I though about something like that: 'code'(rowTemplate2(ii).value = "xx";) but it's doesn't work too.

Comment: ah ok... well ... i need those infos to help you :D  but if you just add `$("#template2").find('input:empty').val('xx')` after your appending of the template, this should work.. maybe the writer of the code changed content of jQuery .. the `$.form` function seems to be inserted by him/her

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64395/discussion-between-mephiztopheles-and-koin-arab).